# calculus expressions

Tags: calculus, integration

Simple question here that I can't Google and have the time for to look it up through all the info on the web available... I also don't know how to import mathematical signs. Could you maybe explain that as well? Sorry for  the inconvenience.

The "f" sign in calculus is used to denote the integral, and I know it in the standard form with b above the f and a under the f, next to the f the function and then dx after that to express the integral of a function on the interval [a, b].
Now I met a another way to note it, its the same f with a circle in the middle (?) and a f with a collection of coordinates called sigma under the f and an alpha after the f, to express some kind of "volume" of a polygon? BTW it is on this site http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Shoelace_Theorem in case this is really unreadable for you. I could understand that.

gr. and thanks

Comment: Yes, this is really unreadable for me.

Comment: f = $\int\;?\;$ That's what I'm assuming.

Comment: Talking about $\int^b_a$ and $\oint$ ?

Comment: YES thanks! how did you add those symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly beyond your level (at least for now) you should wait until the time comes to learn it. But, if you're interested in going beyond you should look at the vector calculus chapter of your book. The circle on the integral like this, 
$$\oint$$ 
is the integral over a closed curve.

And the  $$\int_A$$

represents the integral on a region $A$.

If the integral had a function to integrate like this,
$$\int_A f(x) \space dx \space \text{where} f(x) \neq 1$$

Then it would be equal to a volume of a particular shape.

To represent something in TEX first introduce the "\$" to start the code and end it with a "\$". You can use "\$\$" to make your equation centralized. Remember to finish it with "\$\$". To represent an integral use "\int". You can find other equivalents at those two sites:

- http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#List_of_Mathematical_Symbols

Comment: Note that $\int_A$ is actually a double integral $\int\int$. Just a short notation.

Comment: Ok, very interesting. Never heard of vector calculus or integrals of regions, would like to go into them but were just doing "standard" high school integrals right now

Comment: Could you elaborate on how these integrals work and introduce me a bit? That would be very helpful

Comment: It would require an introduction to multi-variable calculus that would take well beyond the space limited by an answer I can provide over here. Since you are in High School I don't think you're using any calculus devoted books like Stewart or Anton's Calculus Book. I suggest you check out Anton's books. Make sure to go through Vector & Space(3D) until multiple integrals.

Comment: @user209347 And if you have specific questions then come back over here to ask them.

Comment: @user209347 I added some info about representing mathematical symbols in LaTex.